# In need of simple jquery pictures viewer plugin

Tags: jquery, slideshow, image

I need to display either a set of pictures or a video on a web page depending on the data. The video will be displayed with a flash or some other plug-in, but for a set of pictures I want to do it with javascript/jquery. I want to give the plug-in a set of images, and the plug-in would have only basic controls - the buttons for previous picture, next picture, play/pause slide show and stop slide show. Basically it would emulate a controllable animated GIF. It would also be nice if the controls are skinnable to make it at least somewhat consistent with the video plug-in.

Now I wouldn't ask this question if I found something similar, but google/bing point to many, many fancy image viewers and I want to keep it really simple (gallery view, zooming, sliding, dimming, overlays or other animation and effects would just look off) and on the other hand i don't want to code it myself if it already exists. So, has anyone stumbled upon anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Fancybox seems to be a very good plugin for your wants. We use it where I work, and it's pretty simple to use for many needs. It looks great, to boot.</strike>

**EDIT**: based on your comment, perhaps you want something from [25 jQuery Slider/Image Gallery Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/). I'm sorry I cannot give you a comment on them.

Comment: thank you for the link, but as it says on the homepage "FancyBox is a tool for displaying images...that floats overtop of web page." Maybe I wasn't clear, but I need something that displays images inline.

Comment: There were some nice widgets there, but in the end I chose to roll up my own. Thank you for the help though.